# Prisma delete many to many relationship with Composite Key

Tags: mysql, prisma, prisma2

I have this schema here:

```
model label {
  title         String          @id @db.VarChar(16)
  color         String          @db.VarChar(16)
  labelplaylist labelplaylist[]
}

model labelplaylist {
  playlistId Int
  labelId    String   @db.VarChar(16)
  label      label    @relation(fields: [labelId], references: [title])
  playlist   playlist @relation(fields: [playlistId], references: [id])

  @@id([playlistId, labelId])
  @@index([labelId], name: "labelId")
}

model playlist {
  id              Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt       DateTime?       @default(now()) @db.DateTime(0)
  title           String          @db.VarChar(100)
  labelplaylist   labelplaylist[]

  @@index([userId], name: "userId")
}
```

And I would like to delete only the relation between the label and the playlist table. I tried it to do like this:

```
const deleteRelation = await prisma.labelplaylist.delete({
    where: {
        playlistId_labelId: 
    },
})
```

I have the primary key of the label and playlist table, but I don't know how I get the primary key => playlistId_labelId.

Thank's for helping out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the syntax for queries with composite key

```js
    const deleteRelation = await prisma.labelplaylist.delete({
        where: {
            playlistId_labelId: {
                playlistId: playListIdVariable, //replace with appropriate variable
                labelId: labelIdVariable, //replace with appropriate variable
            },
        },
    });
```

You can read more in the **get record by compound ID or compound unique identifier** subsection of the [CRUD Reference Guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#get-record-by-compound-id-or-compound-unique-identifier) in the Prisma docs. This reference shows reading data, but the `where` condition is similar for delete and update as well.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's an **explicit** many-to-many relationship, nested `deleteMany` only deletes relation table records, acting like a `disconnect`. You can then [write your query like that](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#delete-all-related-records):

```js
await req.db.playlist.update({
  data: {
    labels: {
      deleteMany: {},
    },
  },
  where: {
    id: labelId,
  },
})
```

or the other way around.

It won't delete your related table records but only the links between them.